# How to mock chain of method calls using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a function like this:

```
    @Override
        public ClassA createViewModel(ClassB product, ClassC classCVar)
                throws ModuleException
        {
            ClassA classAVar = ClassA.builder().build();
            try {
                if (product != null && product.getProductData() != null) {

                    String gl_name = product.getProductData().offers().get(0).productCategory().asProductCategory()
                            .inlined().map(ProductCategory::glProductGroup).map(ProductCategory.GLProductGroup::symbol)
                            .orElse("");
                    classAVar.setName = gl_name;

                }
                return classAVar;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // some lines of code.
            }
```

I have a line here like String gl_name = ............
which contains a chain of method calls.
Now I want to mock this function using Mockito and want a final result out of all these function calls simply like gl_name = "abc";

How can I do this?

I have created a new function and had put the chain of method calls inside it like this:

```
public String fetchGLNameFunction(ClassB product)
    {
        String gl_name_result = product.getProductData().offers().get(0).productCategory().asProductCategory()
                .inlined().map(ProductCategory::glProductGroup).map(ProductCategory.GLProductGroup::symbol)
                .orElse("");
        return gl_name_result;
    }
```

And now I have tried to create a mock like this:

```
@Mock
    private ClassA classAVar;
..........
............

@Test
    public void testfunction1() throws Exception
    {
        when(classAVar.fetchGLNameFromAmazonAPI(classBVar)).thenReturn("abc");
```

It is still giving me NullPointerException because it is executing my newly created function.

Comment: Either you : 1) create a ClassB object which chain call would result in "abc". 2) Or you mock a classB object but then you gotta chain mock every chained calls. 
This is somewhat related to the Law of demeter.
3) Or you create a method in classB that will do all those chained call, that way you only have to mock that one method

Comment: I have edited the question and tried implementing the third way you told.
But its still giving me the NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you post your whole test please?
How do you inject the `classAVar` in your test? You need to mock `ClassA.builder().build();` and make it return the mock object `classAVar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Mockito` you need to define the behavior of your mock objects.

```
    //  create mock
    ClassB product = mock(ClassB.class);

    // Define the other mocks from your chain:
    // X, Y, Z, ...

    // define return value for method getProductData()
    when(product.getProductData()).thenReturn(X);
    when(X.offers()).thenReturn(Y);
    when(Y.get(0)()).thenReturn(Z); // And so on.... until the last mock object will return "abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should  mock the dependencies that you want to isolate and not the data/model of your test.
Mocking the parameter of the tested method will make it much less readable as you will have to mock many things.

Your chain of methods has multiple scenarios, so test each one of them by creating as fixture a B instance corresponding to each one of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito has a feature called *deep stubbing/mocking*. It lets you mock a chain of calls as a single mock.

```
Builder builder = Mockito.mock(Builder.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
 
Mockito.when(
    builder.newObject()
           .withId(1)
           .withName("My Object")
           .withDescription("Some description")
           .build()
).thenReturn(anObject);
 
// Use the mock...
someService.someServiceMethod(builder);
```

However, it should be noted that deep mocking is generally discouraged.
Deep in the mockito code you will find a comment that reads: *Every time a mock returns a mock a fairy dies*.

See this page for tips on when to use deep mocking, and why it is bad: https://tuhrig.de/everytime-a-mock-returns-a-mock-a-fairy-dies/

I would especially advise against mocking each of the object/method calls individually as even the tiniest amount of refactoring is likely to break the test code.